# Runtime of power of 2 iteration

Tags: time-complexity, runtime

For example:

```
for (int i = 2; i <=n; i = pow(i,2)) // O(1) time here)
```

Would log(log(n)) be correct from 2 4 16 256 ... 2^(2^n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the time complexity of this loop would be *O(log(log(n)))*.

Motivation:
`i` grows as *((2^2)^2)^...^2 = 2<sup>(2 * 2 * ... * 2)</sup> = 2<sup>2^(k-1)</sup>* where *k* is the number of iterations. Thus we must solve:

*n = 2<sup>2^(k-1)</sup>*

*log<sub>2</sub>(n) = 2<sup>(k-1)</sup>*

*log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n)) = k-1*

*k = log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n)) + 1 = O(log(log(n))*. ▢

Comment: Thank you! How did you learn runtime analysis? I feel like I am on the edge of being beginner and intermediate and most resources online are either for newbies or random very hard problems I find without solutions.

Comment: @user818415 I understand your point. I personally learned it the mathematical way - staring at the definition of Big-O and seeing how nice properties follow. (And do exercises. Traditional undergraduate literature might be more useful here than online resources.) It requires some frustration to get the intuition from the rigorous definitions, but it will help you solve also more exotic cases like this one :)

Comment: @user818415 If this answer helped you, could you consider accepting it, by clicking the green check mark? I suggest you do so with your other questions too, if someone has posted a helpful answer. If not, it would help to know what else you are looking for in the question.